# Ajax not getting sucess reponse from django back-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying this below requirement where there is a voice synthesizer and it converts my voice (which is a question) into a text and it sends that text to the back-end Django through Ajax.

At the back-end, Django takes that data and use that data (question) to access the database and get the result and send that result to the frontend which should get caught by the success part of the Ajax. But it's not working.

I am not able to figure out where is the problem. I am posting the Ajax and Django code below for your reference.

**views.py**

```
def GetAnswer(request):
    if request.method=='GET' and request.is_ajax():
        question_asked=str(request.GET.get("message_now"))
        try:
            answer=QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked).value_list('answer', flat=True)[0]
            print(answer)
            data={"data":answer}

            return JsonResponse({"success": True}, data, status=200)
        except:

            return JsonResponse({"success": False}, status=400)
    else:
        print("Not Suceess")
```

**main.js**

```
function chatbotvoice(message) {
  const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

  if (message !== null && message !== '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getanswer",
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        message_now: message
      },
      success: function (data) {
        speech.text = JSON.parse(data);
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        chatareamain.appendChild(showchatbotmsg(speech.text));
      },
      error: function (error) {

        speech.text = "Oh No!! I don't Know !! I am still learning!! Your question got recorded and answer for your question will be available with me in 24 hours";
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        chatareamain.appendChild(showchatbotmsg(speech.text));
      },
    });
  }
}
```

I tried to check whether the Ajax request is reaching the function and I am able to view the value of the variable "question_asked" in the back-end.

Comment: what error is showing in terminal

Comment: i am getting error as "Bad Request:/getanswer/"

Comment: show code of url.py

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.QuestionAnswer, name='QuestionAnswer'),
    path('getanswer/', views.GetAnswer, name = 'getanswer'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Answer (score 0):

```py
return JsonResponse({"success": True}, data, status=200)
```

that line will fail with some error message, because you pass data as a second positional argument. Django documentation tells you that second positional argument is `encoder`. Since a list with data isn't an encoder - you will get an error.

Your error would be catched by try/except block. So the execution flow will move to `except` block - where you return `{"success": false}` JSON response.

So your code should become like this:

```py
def GetAnswer(request):
    if request.method=='GET' and request.is_ajax():
        question_asked=str(request.GET.get("message_now"))
        try:
            answer=QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked).value_list('answer', flat=True)[0]
            print(answer)
            data={"data":answer}

            return JsonResponse({"success": True, "data": data}, status=200)
        except:

            return JsonResponse({"success": False}, status=400)
    else:
        print("Not Suceess")
```

Please, refer to this part of documentation for more details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

---

**UPDATE (21.09.2020)**

You should fix this line:

```py
answer=QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked).value_list('answer', flat=True)[0]
```

to

```py
answer=QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked).values_list('answer', flat=True)[0]
```

because there's no `value_list` function, but there's `values_list`.

**UPDATE 2 (21.09.2020)**

So the final code should be:

```py
def GetAnswer(request):
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.is_ajax():
        question_asked = request.GET["message_now"]
        try:
            answer = QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked).values_list('answer', flat=True)[0]
            return JsonResponse({"success": True, "answer": answer}, status=200)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({"success": False}, status=400)
```

and JS code should be modified as well

```js
function chatbotvoice(message) {
  const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

  if (message !== null && message !== '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getanswer",
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        message_now: message
      },
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.success == true){
          speech.text = data.answer;
          window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
          chatareamain.appendChild(showchatbotmsg(speech.text));
        } else {
          speech.text = "Oh No!! I don't Know !! I am still learning!! Your question got recorded and answer for your question will be available with me in 24 hours";
          window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
          chatareamain.appendChild(showchatbotmsg(speech.text));
        }
      },
      error: function (error) {
        speech.text = "Oh No!! I don't Know !! I am still learning!! Your question got recorded and answer for your question will be available with me in 24 hours";
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
        chatareamain.appendChild(showchatbotmsg(speech.text));
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: print(answer) is not printing anything....i checked it...no values is getting printed

Comment: Do you see bad request in browser console or in Django log? Could you set DEBUG=True and try again?

Comment: i mean in command prompt where i am running this project..and yes DEBUG=True already

Comment: Then can you open that APIon browser tab to see the error details?

Comment: I am new to django and i dont know how to do it...could you please help me?

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getanswer?message_now=Hello" or use Chrome Developer Tools https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference to inspect the response of XHR request (or click with right mouse button and choose "open in new tab"

Comment: If that will not help we can create a chat here on stackoverflow to discuss your problem in realtime

Comment: Bro i modified some and now i am getting this error -->Object of type QuestionAnswer is not JSON serializable

Comment: So that `print(answer)` should work now. What do you see? Also you should fix `            answer=QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked).value_list('answer', flat=True)[0]` (it should have `values_list`. I will update my answer.

Comment: The same error" QuestionAnswer is not JSON serialaizable" on the print

Comment: You shouldn’t get that error. How about to move from comments to chat?

Comment: @SyedSheikAbdullah please make sure that you don't use line like this `answer=QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked)[0]`. You should use `answer=QuestionAnswer.objects.filter(question=question_asked).value_list('answer', flat=True)[0]` instead.

Comment: I have found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979580/object-of-type-questionanswer-is-not-json-serializable that you have wrong line in your python code. Make sure that you have code like in my answer.

Comment: Please use latest python/js code from my answer. It should make your app working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  url: "{% url 'getanswer' %}",
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    message_now: message,
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
  },
```

Comment: Surya,,Ajax is able to take my data to backend...but its not sending the data back to ajax sucess

Comment: Bro..its printing only "Bad Request:/getanswer/" and the 404

Comment: and the thing is failure part is getting played...but the problem is with sucess part

Comment: except Exception as e:
    print(e)

Comment: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' --> this error i am getting

Comment: rename your view function

Comment: You mean def GetAnswer(request): to something else?

Comment: but how renaming has effect bro?

Comment: change it first and try

Comment: i still cant figure out why (function' object has no attribute 'objects') this error is getting geenrated

Comment: Is there a praticular reason why you're using GET and not POST for the AJAX? 
If you're sending data like you do, you really should do POST requests

Comment: i am only getting values bro,,,,thats why i am using GET

Comment: POST is used if in case any updation is needed....but i am just fetching the values so am using GET